# Python save file to csv

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code that gets in Twitter tweets and should process the data and after that save into a new file.

This is the code:

```
#import regex
import re

#start process_tweet
def processTweet(tweet):
    # process the tweets

    #Convert to lower case
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    #Convert www.* or https?://* to URL
    tweet = re.sub('((www\.[\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL',tweet)
    #Convert @username to AT_USER
    tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+','AT_USER',tweet)
    #Remove additional white spaces
    tweet = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', tweet)
    #Replace #word with word
    tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', tweet)
    #trim
    tweet = tweet.strip('\'"')
    return tweet
#end

#Read the tweets one by one and process it
input = open('withoutEmptylines.csv', 'rb')
output = open('editedTweets.csv','wb')

line = input.readline()

while line:
    processedTweet = processTweet(line)
    print (processedTweet)
    output.write(processedTweet)
    line = input.readline()

input.close()
output.close()
```

My data in the input file looks like this, so each tweet in one line:

```
She wants to ride my BMW the go for a ride in my BMW lol http://t.co/FeoNg48AQZ
BMW Sees U.S. As Top Market For 2015 i8 http://t.co/kkFyiBDcaP
```

my function is working good, but I am not happy with the output which looks like this:

```
she wants to ride my bmw the go for a ride in my bmw lol URL rt AT_USER Ðun bmw es mucho? yo: bmw. -AT_USER veeergaaa!. hahahahahahahahaha nos hiciste la noche caray!
```

so it puts everything in one row and not each tweet in one row as was the format in the input file.

Has someone an idea to get each tweet in one line?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects

Comment: Try: `output.write(processedTweet + '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

With a example file like this:

```
tweet number one
tweet number two
tweet number three
```

This code:

```
file = open('tweets.txt')
for line in file:
   print line
```

Produces this output:

```
tweet number one

tweet number two

tweet number three
```

Python is reading in the endlines just fine, but your script is replacing them via regular expression substitution.

this regex substitution:

```
tweet = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', tweet)
```

Is converting all of your white space characters (e.g tabs and new lines) into single spaces.

Either add a endline onto the tweet before you output it, or modify your regex to not substitute endlines like so:

```
tweet = re.sub('[ ]+', ' ', tweet)
```

EDIT: I put my test substitution command in there. the suggestion has been fixed.