# Striping space while preserving new line separator python

Tags: python, newline, space, strip

I want to strip spaces to single space but preserve one empty line separator in a file. I have tried the following code and it seems to work.

How can I do this with out writing to the file twice?

I want to collect all my substitutions may be in a text file and write them all at once.

```
i = open('inputfile.txt','r')
infile = i.readlines()
o = open('outputfile.txt','w')
for line in infile:
    if line == '\n':
        o.write('\n\n')
    else:
        o.write(re.sub(r'\s+',' ',line))
o.close()
i.close()
```

Comment: Why don't you like the code you have?

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by writing twice?  Did you just want to store all the data and do a single write call? (Also you're missing a tab for your else)

Comment: @Foon, thats is exactly what i want, sorry for the confusion .I was thinking of "text" or just string when i wrote "text file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer in this question here: [Python save file to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813163/python-save-file-to-csv/18813443#18813443)

I think the `re.sub()` replacement is tripping you up with the `'\s'` value. Just replace `' '` instead.

Comment: brandosimpkins, your solution worked. I changed `r'\s+'` with       `[ ]+` and remove `if...else`. I also got the idea of storing intermediate results from the question asked over there. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = open('inputfile.txt','r')
infile = i.readlines()
o = open('outputfile.txt','w')
newoutputfile = ""
for line in infile:
        if line == '\n':
                newoutputfile+= '\n\n'
else:
        newoutputfile +=' '.join(line.split())
o.write(newoutputfile)
o.close()
```

Comment: It would helpful to others if you updated your answer with a brief explanation of how this works, and what it does differently.

Comment: LeonardoPF, i was looking for something like ur solution here, but i think ur code is overwriting. it displays only the new lines and the last sentence in the input file.

Comment: This has an incorrect else that is aligned to the for loop instead of the intended if block inside of the foor loop.  Python has a handy but under-recognized feature that you can have a else which matches the for loop (and gets executed if your for loop executes normally).  This is why it was doing the behavior you're seeing.  (Of course, I was thinking it executed the else if the list-like object was empty, which I could see as also being useful for different reasons)

Comment: @Leigh this does what math had intended to say, which is that it (with the else tabbed over properly) builds a string containing all the data and then does a single write)